# php mysql html pagination not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

I am trying to get the pagination work, everything works fine apart from pagination.

I am using PHP, HTML, and MYSQL. I can fetch the records fine but all the records on the web page shows up, I just want to limit it to show 10 per page.

Dont know what I am doing wrong here.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<head>
<title>Paging Using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'useer';
$dbpass = 'passwoord';
$rec_limit = 10;

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('disks');
/* Get total number of records */
$sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM hdd ";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
$rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
   $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}

        echo '<h3>',Table,'</h3>';

$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$sql = "SELECT cust, manu, model, serial, capacity, firmware, deviceid, ataver, ltime, date, ourref, result FROM hdd";
       "FROM hdd".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
echo '<tr><th>Customer</th> <th>HDD Type</th> <th>Model</th> <th>Serial</th> <th>Size</th> <th>Firmware</th> <th>Device ID</th> <th>ATA Ver</th> <th>Manufactured On</th> <th>date</th> <th>ourref</th> <th>result</th></tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo '<tr>';
$i=0;
                        foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
 if($i==10) break;
                                echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
                        }
                        echo '</tr>';
}
                echo '</table><br />';
if( $page > 0 )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

How can I get this to display only 10 records per page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$_GET['page']`  instead of `$_GET{'page'}`?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are obsolete. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your SQL query. You have:

```
$sql = "SELECT cust, manu, model, serial, capacity, firmware, deviceid, ataver, ltime, date, ourref, result FROM hdd";
       "FROM hdd".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
```

Where it should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT cust, manu, model, serial, capacity, firmware, deviceid, ataver, ltime, date, ourref, result FROM hdd ";
$sql .= "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
```

Also I agree with what John mentioned. You have $_GET{'page'} and it should be $_GET['page'] in both places.

Comment: Thank you, correct.  it is working as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

Why you use $_GET{'page'}? 
Change $_GET{'page'} to $_GET['page'].